# How to make a uibutton with touch down action and touch up inside action

Tags: objective-c

I need to make one button with two actions, touch down used to play a sound and then touch up inside to stop playing the sound when you let go of the button

Comment: A `UIButton` is a SubClass of `UIControl`. The first step you should do is to check out Apples Documentation about the Classes you use. You can simply alt+click on the classname to jump directly in the documentation.

Here the documentation about addTarget (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIControl/addTarget:action:forControlEvents:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Connect two methods to both these actions.

```
[self.yourBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(touchDownMethod:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[self.yourBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(touchUpInsideMethod:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```